# 60 amp sub panel, 100 ft away from main panel. Grounding rod or not?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

Adding a 60amp sub panel (4breakers) on the 2nd floor for a dehumidification  system and some misc.  Running 100 feet of 6/3 wire.  I am assuming that I can use the ground wire in the 6/3 from that sub panel ground bar to the main panel ground bar. This is not in a separate building so I don’t think NEC requires grounding rods. 
And if so does anyone know the limitation on the length of a ground wire if indeed a separate one is required for the panel itself.  Washington country Maryland.

Comment: Is your 6/3 NM or SE? (It does matter a bit in terms of margin for growth -- SE can use the 75degC ampacity, while NM *cannot*)

Comment: It’s nm but there won’t be any significant loads near 60A.  Usually just a 38A startup and then 31mca down to 30a or lower in reality. The panel was just for some items I may not think of right now.  I needed a 40 amp circuit 100 feet away.  So I needed to run 6 and figured having a few empt slots can’t hurt so I’m gonna run 6/3 not 6/2 and have a little panel. :-). Just was concerned about the code for the ground on the sub panel.

Comment: In the same building or attached building no ground rod is required just hot hot neutral ground, with ground and neutral being isolated from each other in the sub panel.

Answer (score 2):

Same building, just supply ground and neutral in appropriate sizes and separate, and be sure that ground and neutral are not bonded in the sub-panel.

6AWG copper (as a cable, which typically limits you to the 60C rating...) is maybe pushing it a bit depending how loaded that 60A panel is.

Comment: It’s for a specific item The MCA is only 31A on the tag (3 ton) And the short heavy load startup only needs a 40a breaker it’s for a dehumidifier. So I think I’ll be fine even st the 100 foot run? Thanks for the help. The other few slots will be for smaller misc stuff I may need on the roof at a later date.